Postgres dblink Problem, SQL state: 2F003 - password required
what I would like to acconplish:
Having access to a postgres dababase with a readonly user to database a.
This problem is solved. The user-account is up an running - I can read all tables and views in database a.
Except; there are some views which pull some information via dblink from other databases (on the same server).
This is no problem when using the default user - this is a problem, when using the readonly user...
When logging into the other database with the read-only user - I have complete access and can read and view any table and view. So I would assume there is no problem with the readonly account itself.
Doing some readings/research I understand that in this case - dblink is required to work with full credentials.
So what I try is this...
SELECT company_projects.databasename,
    company_projects.project_id,
    company_projects.code,
    company_projects.description,
    company_projects.customer
   FROM dblink('hostaddr=192.123.45.67 port=5432 user=readonly_user password=ThePassword dbname=company_global', 'select databasename, project_id, code, description, customer from company_projects'::text) company_projects(databasename text, project_id integer, code text, description text, customer text);

The result will be:
'ViewCommand' object has no attribute 'auto_commit'ERROR:  Non-superusers must provide a password in the connection string.password is required 

FEHLER:  password is required
SQL state: 2F003
Detail: Non-superusers must provide a password in the connection string.

Version Info:
"PostgreSQL 11.12 (Debian 11.12-0+deb10u1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit"
any hints are welcome.
If this would work I would then have a look into storing the credentials in the .pgpass file which sounds like a much better idea than having these in the sql string...
KR, Martin

I suspect the connection string you gave us is not the real one, and the real one has some kind of problem being parsed.  There is a bug in dblink which interprets any problem parsing the connection string as being a missing password.

Where does the message "'ViewCommand' object has no attribute 'auto_commit'" come from?  I don't think that that is a PostgreSQL message.  It isn't clear to me how that is related, but it might be.

Hi jjanes...
the string is as real as can be. I simply altered some database names and the ip and the password. When using the default user - this string is working fine...
Die Resultmessage is the message I receive after sendig the command to pastgres... I'm using pgAdmin so this is the answer pgAdmin is giving me.
KR.

It is real, except that you changed most of the values?  I would say one of those values you changed contains some special character which breaks the parsing (probably the password, as that is the most likely one to contain special characters)
